# Panda deletes last column of my dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

These are my first steps with Python and I'm sure it's a very simple problem but I'm getting crazy.
I have a data frame where `dataframe.head()` shows me a table 5 rows × 81 columns:

```
df_TRAIN= pd.read_csv(url_DATATRAIN)
df_TRAIN.head()
```

But when I tried to verify types or calculate functions as `mean`, `max`,... the last column disappears.
For example,

```
df_TRAIN.dtypes
```

```
Id                 int64
MSSubClass         int64
MSZoning          object
LotFrontage      float64
LotArea            int64
                  ...   
MiscVal            int64
MoSold             int64
YrSold             int64
SaleType          object
SaleCondition     object
Length: 80, dtype: object
```

You can see I have a length 80.

I have tried with `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 120)` but I think it's only to display.

Could you help me?
Thanks a lot in advance

SOLUTION -edit-
I have restarted my CP and Jupyter Notebook and It works.

Comment: There is no code between `pd.read_csv(url_DATATRAIN)` and `df_TRAIN.dtypes` ?

Comment: Hello Jezrael,No code :(

Comment: what is the name of the column that doesn't display? what does ```df_TRAIN.shape``` show

Comment: Hello Baby desta, using shape it shows (1460, 81). The name of the last column is SalePrice

Comment: please restart your jupyter notebook, and do everything again. you probably added code unintentionaly

Comment: I have just restart PC and Jupyter and It works! I was getting crazy! Thanks a lot!!!!!